# SQL expression for when .... then ....does not work properly

Tags: sql, qgis

I am kind of new to qgis and this forum but I have a problem for which i would like some help. I made a raster layer indicating different landcovers based on an image. I now want to assign the most frequently found landcover within a polygon to be assigned to that polygon. I intended to do this by counting the landcover pixels within the polygons and then making a new field in the attribute table from to polygon to assign the highest count of pixels to the field. i intended to do this using a when ... then ... expression. However, this is not going right, it first of all does not assign a value to all the records, so some get a 'null' value. Also in some situation it actually does not assign the highest count to the new field.

[raster and polygon field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0osgn.png)

[Expression part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4pqI.png)

[Expression part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEB5h.png)

[Result from the expression in attribute table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn7iA.png)
As can be seen in this figure, landuse3 has 'null' values and the highlighted record is also incorrect, the result should be 'road' instead of 'flat roof'.

It would be really nice if someone could help me out with this :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.